# XPATH expression to navigate to next page

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to write an XPATH expression that finds the ">" symbol on this page to navigate to the next page. The website is:

http://classifieds.kelownadailycourier.ca/kelowna/automotive/search

I am using it in this segment of code (the 'loop' tag):

```
    <name>
    <loop xpath='//A[contains(.,">")]'>
       <follow xpath='... '>
            <extract xpath='...' />
       </follow>
    </loop>
    </name>
```

As you can see, I tried to come up with an XPATH already but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you can also use `//A[contains(.,"&gt;")]`

Comment: @PhilVallone that won't change anything, it's just an alternative representation for exactly the same XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath you've given would look for elements named `A` which are not in a namespace, but in the file you've linked to the element you're looking for is named `a` (lower case - remember XML, and thus XHTML, is case sensitive) and is in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace because of the `xmlns="..."` on the root `html` element.  You would need to bind a prefix to that namespace URI and then use that prefix in the XPath expressions.

You haven't said what technology you're using to evaluate the XPath expressions, so I don't know whether it's sufficient simply to add `xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to your XML or whether the tool you're using requires a different method to declare namespaces for use in XPath, but once you can get the prefix declared then

```
//h:a[contains(., ">")]
```

should work.  Alternatively you might want to go for something more specific to this particular element, such as

```
//h:li[contains(@class, "ap_paginator_next_page")]/h:a
```